# XAML- how to set the size of a ScrollViewer dynamically?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dynamic

I am displaying a `<ScrollViewer>` in my application window using XAML. At the moment, I am specifying the size of the `<ScrollViewer>` statically (i.e. giving it a set value, which cannot be changed while the application is running):

```
<Window>
    <Grid>
        <TabControl>
            <TabItem>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Grid>
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="scroller" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="39,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="244" Width="450">
                            <TextBox x:Name="infoPane" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="nothing" IsReadOnly="True" />
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

What I want to do, is dynamically set the width of the `<ScrollViewer>` to half the width of the application window, so that it will always cover half of the displayed content.

The user can re-size the application window by dragging one of the corners or edges of the window, so the area of the display that the `<ScrollViewer>` takes up should automatically always be half of the width of the application window, whatever that is.

Is there a way that I can dynamically set the value of the `<ScrollViewer>` `Width` property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the width and height of current window call `Window.Current.Bounds.Width` / `.Height` . Just divide by two to get what you want. Setting the value dynamically is also easy: `scroller.Width = value`. You could consider creating a Grid with 2 Columns both with `Width="*"` and place the ScrollViewer in one of them to get the exact same effect you want.

**EDIT**

Here's what I meant in the second part of my answer:

```
<Window>
<Grid>
    <TabControl>
        <TabItem>
            <StackPanel>
                <Grid>
                     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />

                     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="scroller" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="39,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="244" Width="{Binding ActualWidth,RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
                           Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Grid}}">
                        <TextBox x:Name="infoPane" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="nothing" IsReadOnly="True" />
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Where would I put the call to `Window.Current.Bounds.Width`? In the XAML or C#? At the moment, I get compile error when trying to do it in either... In the XAML, `Width="Window...."` will give an error saying `Invalid value for property 'width', and in the C#, if I do `MainWindow.`, the only 'width' properties that are shown in the autocomplete are: `ActualWidthProperty`, which identifies a dependency property, and `WidthProperty`, which also identifies a dependency property... i.e. neither actually return a value for the width of the window.

Comment: I posted code of how I meant the second part of my answer which you should focus on!

Comment: Hey, thanks for the update- I'll give it a try now. But just looking at that, and thinking about it- doesn't it mean that I will just be dividing my main window display into two, and showing the `<ScrollViewer>` in one of them...  so it's not making a difference to the actual size of the `<ScrollViewer>`, it's just changing the size of the space where that will be displayed. i.e. if I did this, and manually resized my window when the application is running, the size of the `<ScrollViewer>` would still be fixed at whatever value I've set its `width` property to, wouldn't it?

Comment: If you set the HorizontalAlignment of the ScrollViewer to Stretch it will always fill the space it has. So it will always fill half of the screen in this case.

Comment: Yep- just given that a go, and it's done exactly what I thought... my main window is now divided into two columns, and the `<ScrollViewer>` is displayed in the left hand one, at the size I've specified in the `width` property, and stays that size no matter what size I resize the main window to... but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Look at what I just wrote!! HorizontalAilgnment="Stretch" and delete the Width you provided. I updated the answer, have a look!

Comment: Setting the `HorizontalAlignment` of the `ScrollViewer` to `Stretch` didn't make a difference to the width of it as it was displayed... just put it in the middle of that column, rather than on the right hand side of it.

Comment: Literally just gave it a go- I think we wrote our previous comments at the same time...

Comment: If it still doesn't work have a look now. I updated the Width property!

Comment: Ah brilliant- that is working now- thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Oh my bad, I misunderstood : Can you give your whole XAML ?

Dynamic way is : 
`width="x*"`
Where x is a number. 
But if you give the whole XAML I could make an example.

Edit :

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ScrollViewer x:Name="scroller" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <TextBox x:Name="infoPane" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="nothing" IsReadOnly="True" />
    </ScrollViewer>

</Grid>
```

Comment: I've updated my question to include the full structure of my XAML.